# Plogger gallery -- simple customization question

Tags: php, image, gallery

I'm wondering if it's possible via a simple edit to the Plogger template to display filenames under thumbnails instead of the default "caption"? I'm creating a large gallery and need to have a descriptive name under the thumbs and at this point must manually add a caption for each. An example can be viewed [**here**](http://www.plogger.org/demo/?level=album&id=4) (note that no text appears under the thumbs b/c captions were not added).

Thanks for any assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

well I feel silly, but it's all a learning process... to those on here who might encounter the same question in modifying the Plogger gallery script, I discovered after some digging through the source that I could simply change "plogger_get_picture_caption" to "plogger_get_picture_filename" in the album.php file within the appropriate theme directory. rather logical solution :)

Comment: something I'm actually still trying to figure out, now that I've modified the plogger template to display filenames under the thumbs instead of captions, is how to keep the filename text from being changed to all lowercase. there is a "sanitize_filename" function in the "plog-functions.php" file that manipulates the characters of filenames, but the change to lowercase seems to be happening elsewhere? if anyone is familiar with the Plogger source, or feels like taking a gander at it, I'd be most appreciative of any guidance here (the plogger support forum seems to be dead).

Answer (score 0):

The import script does not store the case of the original filename, so the best way to get it is while importing.

You can modify /plog-admin/plog-import.php to put the filename in the caption field when importing by changing the line (315?) that reads:

```
<input type="text" size="60" style="width: 95%;" name="captions['.$file_key.']" /><br />
```

to:

```
<input type="text" size="60" style="width: 95%;" name="captions['.$file_key.']" value="'.substr(basename($files[$i]), 0, -4).'" /><br />
```